# Getting systematically NOTUSED special token as generated word in Huggingface causal language model

Tags: python, huggingface

I am using the following code with camembert causal language model (a Huggingface model in French) to generate sentences. But I keep getting NOTUSED as generated word.

```
camembert = CamembertForCausalLM.from_pretrained('camembert-base')
tokenizer = CamembertTokenizer.from_pretrained('camembert-base')

phrase = 'Ceci est une '
inputs = tokenizer.encode(phrase, return_tensors='pt')

#Get logits from last layer
last_layer_logits = camembert(inputs).logits[:, -1, :]

#Keep top 10 logits at max; stop if cumulative probability >= 1.0.
top_logits = top_k_top_p_filtering(last_layer_logits, top_k=10, top_p=1.0)

#Softmax the logits into probabilities
probabilities = F.softmax(top_logits, dim=-1)

#Generate next token
generated_next_token = torch.multinomial(probabilities, num_samples=1)
generated = torch.cat([inputs, generated_next_token], dim=-1)

#Get result
result_string = tokenizer.decode(generated.tolist()[0])

print(result_string)
```

Output:
---> <s> Ceci est une </s>NOTUSED

Forcing the logit value of the NOTUSED token to -Inf usually works (though not always), but this does not seem to be the right way to proceed.